# How to improve time complexity of this code piece?

Tags: ruby

I am having a hard time trying to down down the time. If this can be done in O(n^2) thatd be awesome.

```
def printDistance(file)
   line = file.gets

  if line == nil then return end

  sz, sx, sy, ex, ey = line.split(/\s/)
  #counter = 0
  while line = file.gets do
    if line[0...4] == "path"
    else
      x, y, ds, w = line.split(/\s/,4)
      x = x.to_i
      y = y.to_i
      matrix= Array.new
      later = Array.new
      tmp = Array.new
      processing = Array.new
      if matrix[y].class != Array
        matrix[y] = Array.new
      end

      if ds == ""  #this cell has NO way to get to
        matrix[y][x] = nil
      else
        matrix[y][x] = ds
      end
    end
  end
  for y in 0...matrix.length
    processing[y] = Array.new
    tmp[y] = Array.new
    later[y] = Array.new
  end
  printing = Array.new
  counter = 0
  sy = sy.to_i
  sx = sx.to_i
  processing[sy][sx] = matrix[sy][sx]
  matrix[sy][sx] = nil
  puts "#{counter},(#{sx},#{sy})" #first one 
  counter += 1
  loop do
    print "#{counter},"
    counter += 1
    for y in 0...processing.length
      for x in 0...processing[y].length
        if processing[y][x].class != nil 
          tmp[y][x] = processing[y][x]
          dirArr = tmp[y][x].to_s.split(//)
          dirArr.each { |c|
            if c == "u"
              newY = y - 1
              newX = x
            elsif c == "d"
              newY = y + 1
              newX = x
            elsif c == "l"
              newY = y
              newX = x - 1
            else  #c == r
              newY = y
              newX = x + 1
            end
            if matrix[newY][newX] != nil
              tmpStr = "(#{newX},#{newY})"

              printing.unshift(tmpStr)

              later[newY][newX] = matrix[newY][newX]

              matrix[newY][newX] = nil
            end
          }
        end
      end
    end
    printing.sort!
    for i in 0...printing.length
      print printing[i]
      if i < printing.length - 1
        print ","
      end
    end
    printing = []   #resetting
    puts
    for i in 0...later.length
      for j in 0...later[i].length
        if later[i][j] != nil
          processing[i][j] = later[i][j]
        end
      end
    end
    break if NotEmpty(matrix) == false
  end
end

def NotEmpty (a)
  for i in 0...a.length
    for j in 0...a[i].length
      if a[i][j] != nil

        return true
      end
    end
  end
  return false
end
```

Basically this code reads in a file and places it in a 2-d array representing a maze, then based on maze's starting point it will perform a BFS to put all cells in order from closest to the start to the farthest, then print everything out

This code is now O(n^3) but I am trying to shrink it to O(n^2), is there anyway I can traverse a 2-d array and keeping track of the x and y values without using two forloops?
Any help is appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Breadth-first search should be [on the order of the number of edges in your graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), or O(|E|).  You absolutely should *not* be iterating over every value in the graph if you're attempting to do BFS.  First, isolate what you use to represent your graph, then attempt to rework your BFS algorithm based on that.

Comment: It's much less verbose, more Ruby conventional, to use `x = [ ]` than `x = Array.new`. The only reason for using the explicit constructor is to apply arguments to `new`, such as for setting defaults. Likewise, `x.class == Array` is highly discouraged. Instead, `x.is_a?(Array)` does the job. Comparing vs. `false` in an `if` is also redundant. Use `unless` instead. Don't forget to use `underscore_style` when naming methods, not `MixedCase`.